# Functional Infix Implementation in Python

Tags: python, functional-programming

I have a current implementation like this:

```
class Infix(object):
  def __init__(self, func):
    self.func = func
  def __or__(self, other):
    return self.func(other)
  def __ror__(self, other):
    return Infix(partial(self.func, other))
  def __call__(self, v1, v2):
    return self.func(v1, v2)

@Infix
def Map(data, func):
  return list(map(func,data))
```

This is great, it works as expected, however I want to also expand this implementation to allow for a left side only solution.  If somebody can showcase a solution AND explanation, that would be phenomenal.

Here is an example of what I would like to do...

```
 valLabels['annotations'] \
    |Map| (lambda x: x['category_id']) \
    |Unique|
```

Where Unique is defined as below...

```
@Infix
def Unique(data):
    return set(data)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't that an unavoidable syntax error? You can't end a python expression with `|`.

Comment: Have you looked at [coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/) either for your use case, or at their source code? They have an infix notation, for instance, and I believe their syntax is a superset of Python.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist nah, I'm trying to stay with as much vanilla python stuff I have due to a variety of c integrations etc, just gets hairy to move outside that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind dropping the final `|`, you could do

```
class InfixR(object):
  def __init__(self, func):
    self.func = func
  def __ror__(self, other):
    return self.func(other)
  def __call__(self, v1):
    return self.func(v1)

@InfixR
def Unique(data):
  return set(data)
```

Then your expression would look like

```
valLabels['annotations'] \
    |Map| (lambda x: x['category_id']) \
    |Unique
```

---

Your original `Infix` class is (technically) abusing the `bitwise or` operator:  `|Map|` is nothing special, it's just `value | Map | my_lambda`, a "bitwise or" of a list, an object, and a lambda, with a couple of spaces removed, and some newlines inserted (using `\` to prevent the interpretter from trying to treat each line separately).

In custom classes, you can implement many of the usual operators using `__double_underscore__` methods, in the case of bitwise or, they are `__or__` and `__ror__`.

When the python interpreter encounters the `|` operator, it first looks at the object to the right, to see if it has a `__or__` method.  It then calls `left.__or__(right)`.  If that is not defined or returns `NotImplemented`, it looks at the object on the right, for `__ror__` (reversed or), and calls `right.__ror__(left)`.

The other part of this is the decorator notation.

When you say

```
@Infix
def Unique(data):
    return set(data)
```

The interpretter expands that into

```
def Unique(data):
    return set(data)

Unique = Infix(Unique)
```

So you get an `Infix` instance, which has `__or__` and `__ror__` methods, and a `__call__` method.  As you might guess, `my_obj.__call__()` is called when you invoke `my_oby()`.

Comment: You mind adding a little explanation about whats up with this section of code?  I've mashed this together from a variety of sources and not really sure whats going on with it.